# Multiple languages supported for multiple xhtml pages

Tags: jsf, localization, resourcebundle

I'm developing a JSF web project which provides technical tutorials for readers. I ran into a dilemma in which I'll have to support multiple languages for each tutorial page. It's tempting to go with resource bundle but hold on a second, should I really create multiple resource bundles for individual tutorial page...It's gonna be huge if I have 100 tutorial pages and each page support 4 or 5 kinds of language.

How should it be done? Could you tell me your solution, ideas?

Answer (score 0):

define main prop file

```
i18n.properties
and for each language new property 
i18n_ru.properties
i18n_am.properties
i18n_es.properties
```

Comment: Hi! I'm not talking about naming convention for properties file and how to use resource bundle. My question is about if you have 500 xhtml pages for example and each page will have 5 resource bundles for 5 kinds of language then you end up having 2500 properties files stored in server side, how do you deal with this situation?